# The best way to implement a pure newsletter in django?

Tags: python, django, registration, newsletter, django-registration

My django service is a pure newsletter service. The user need not have a password. All the user needs to do is provide an email address. We will be sending the email periodically.

So the user does not have to provide the username and password. But having an email confirmation step is important.

The django-newsletter app requires that the user be registered.  All the well-known user registration apps require a password and often the username also.

Is there a way to add users from email addresses without needing password or username?

Is there a better plugin for newsletter that is not linked to the core user data?

Comment: Just develop your own system.

Comment: That is what I will do if there is no other alternative. I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel.  This is such a simple yet common need, I am surprised this has not been addressed before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did wade through a considerable amount of plugins before finding what I needed. For anyone who is looking for something similar, check out [django-newsletter-signup](https://github.com/bitmazk/django-newsletter-signup)  This is independent of the UserModel.

If you want use the existing user model but not harass the user by requiring them to enter a ton of data, and limit only to email id, then you can do it by using a combination of [custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) and [django-registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but be aware that it will need a little fine tuning before you can use it.